# How do I get my apache server serving my files having accidentally deleted the www directory?

Tags: ubuntu, server, lamp

So now when I reach `localhost` its just empty, I've tried to simply replace the folder with my own `www` folder, but with no luck.

I've also tried to remove my lamp server per:

> Starting over: How to remove the LAMP stack
>   To remove the LAMP stack remove the following packages:
>
> Note: This assumes you have no other programs that require any of these packages. You might wish to simulate this removal first, and only remove the packages that don't cause removal of something desired.
>
> apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 php5-common php5-mysql

and then reinstalling it with: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

I think there is nothing wrong on my server, its just that I cant reach my localhost site.

This is also the first time I am running ubuntu so I might be missing something crucial.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a directory named `html` inside `www`. That is the default [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#documentroot) for Apache.

So create this following path: `/var/www/html`.

Put your files inside the `html` directory to have them show up when you hit http://localhost/.

If creating `/var/www/html` doesn't work then check the apache configuration to see what is the correct path. Usually it is the file `/etc/apache/httpd.conf` or `/etc/httpd/apache.conf`. Look for the statement that looks like the following:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

And then create the path that is given as the value for DocumentRoot.

Comment: So I did what you said. But the "costum" localhost page is still not there. Maybe there isnt anyone when your running it through linux? When I reach `localhost` through wamp on my windows machine, I reach a site where I can access myphpadmin and such.

Comment: Linux does not come with phpmyadmin pre-installed. You have to manually install it either by installing the phpmyadmin apt-get package:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04

Or downloading and putting the phpmyadmin files in the /var/www/html directory.

Comment: I have dont that. I can reach the server, but it cant find localhost/phpmyadmin. dpkg -s phpmyadmin says its all fine